# fibonacci sequence recursive syntax error

Tags: prolog

I tried this code

```
fibonacci(1, 1).
fibonacci(2, 1).
fibonacci(N, F):-
    N1 is N–1,
    N2 is N – 2,
    fibonacci(N1, F1),
    fibonacci(N2, F2),
    F is F1 + F2.
```

but it tells me there is a syntax error at
`N1 is N-1`. Specifically at the N-1 part. Any ideeas?

Comment: Those are not minuses, those are something else. You were copy-pasting from somewhere, or you are using a text editor (Word?) that does strange things with your input. If you really want to get to the bottom of it, you'd have to look at this code in an editor that shows you what character _exactly_ you have. Or do a hexdump. The other option is to re-type your code in a text editor meant for coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you are not using the minus but one of the look alikes (`–`) which appear by using WYSIWYG editors like word. Open the document in a normal text editor of your choice and retype the minuses (`-`).

Comment: There is also the possibility that OP was copy-pasting from an app or a website that does something with certain characters. Like, when `"` become fancy quotes, for example.

Comment: This was it. I was copying from my teacher's pdf. Retyped all and this now works. Thanks